# groupby with calculations in series

Tags: python, series, rolling-computation

I have a series of which this is a snippet:

```
Dates
1988-01-01        NaN
1988-01-04     257.40
1988-01-05     259.80
1988-01-06     258.60
1988-01-07     262.85
1988-01-08     240.75
1988-01-11     247.70
1988-01-12     246.35
1988-01-13     246.25
1988-01-14     247.45
1988-01-15     251.50
...  
2019-03-01    2805.00
2019-03-04    2791.50
2019-03-05    2791.50
2019-03-06    2771.50
2019-03-07    2750.00
2019-03-08    2747.00
2019-03-11    2789.00
2019-03-12    2797.25
2019-03-13    2819.50
2019-03-14    2812.25
2019-03-15    2829.75
Length: 8141, dtype: float64
```

I need to perform a 40 week moving average of this series by weekday: that is, for Mondays, Tuesdays, etc.

I have tried several methods, but only one has been successful.

```
werTarget = werTarget.fillna(method='ffill')
i = 0
while i < 5: # for Monday to Friday, do each weekday separately
    tmpTarget = werTarget[werTarget.index.weekday==i]
    tmpIntmdInd = tmpTarget / tmpTarget.rolling(window=40).mean()
    if i == 0:
        IntmdInd = tmpIntmdInd
    else:
        holdindx = IntmdInd
        i = i + 1
```

It took over two hours to complete, and when I plotted it, every single data point was its own line.

I need a single series as a result, and certainly much faster: Some of the series are longer than this, and there are literally thousands of them.

I tried using something more terse,

```
werTarget = werTarget.fillna(method='ffill')
IntmdInd = werTarget.groupby('weekday').rolling(window=40).mean()
```

but this results in the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-16-1d4ba482ec32>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/MyFile.py', wdir='C:/MyDir')

  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/MyFile.py", line 62, in <module>
    werGraph(sp,werOne)

  File "C:/MyFile.py", line 44, in werGraph
    IntmdInd = werIntmdInd(werRat)

  File "C:/MyFile.py", line 34, in werIntmdInd
    IntmdInd = werTarget.groupby('weekday').rolling(window=75).mean()

  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 7632, in groupby
    observed=observed, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 2110, in groupby
    return klass(obj, by, **kwds)

  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 360, in __init__
    mutated=self.mutated)

  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\grouper.py", line 578, in _get_grouper
    raise KeyError(gpr)

KeyError: 'weekday'
```

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Your original DataFrame doesn't have a column called 'weekday'. Try adding ```werTarget['weekday'] = werTarget.index.weekday``` before running the groupby

Comment: Adding werTarget['weekday'] = werTarget.index.weekday appends an array to the end of the series object:
     2019-03-15 00:00:00                                              2829.75
     weekday                Int64Index([4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3,
        ...
     Length: 8142, dtype: object
     Traceback (most recent call last):
     ...
     ValueError: Grouper and axis must be same length

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where the bug is, because I pretty much used the code from your question.
I'll demonstrate this with some data from pandas_datareader

```
>>> import pandas_datareader as pdr
>>> import pandas as pd  # version 0.24.2
>>>
>>> start = pd.to_datetime('2017-01-01')#datetime(2015, 2, 9)
>>> end = pd.to_datetime('2019-01-01')
>>> f = pdr.data.DataReader('F', 'iex', start, end)
>>> f.head()

               open     high      low    close    volume
date
2017-01-03  10.4286  10.7705  10.3687  10.7619  40510821
2017-01-04  10.9158  11.3432  10.8902  11.2577  77638075
2017-01-05  11.2919  11.3005  10.7961  10.9158  75628443
2017-01-06  10.9414  10.9756  10.8047  10.9072  40315887
2017-01-09  10.9329  10.9927  10.7961  10.7961  39438393
```

Then I just convert the index to datetime, get the weekday, and perform the rolling average on the grouped data

```
>>> f.index = pd.to_datetime(f.index)
>>> f['weekday'] = f.index.weekday
>>> f.groupby('weekday').rolling(40).mean().tail()

                        open      high       low     close        volume  weekday
weekday date
4       2018-11-30  9.750638  9.837815  9.640928  9.727008  4.159594e+07      4.0
        2018-12-07  9.722113  9.811025  9.608238  9.692950  4.213964e+07      4.0
        2018-12-14  9.691435  9.780057  9.578423  9.658573  4.151767e+07      4.0
        2018-12-21  9.644488  9.735150  9.528508  9.605200  4.228912e+07      4.0
        2018-12-28  9.576780  9.670210  9.460493  9.536315  4.145531e+07      4.0
```

Comment: Thank you, Varsavia, but I think you misunderstood my question.  I am looking for the 40-week moving average of the Mondays, the 40-week moving average of the Tuesdays, etc., interlaced into one series (or data frame).